# Rails 7 instance variable not passed to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On a new vanilla Rails 7 project, I'm trying to create a simple view with a form that, when submitted, renders the same view with some additional information.

Here's my controller:

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts "got index request"
    @message = "type something into the form"
  end

  def create
    puts "got create request"
    @message = "hello world"
    render :index
  end
end
```

Here's `index.html.erb`:

```
<p style="color: green"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>New search</h1>

<%= render "form" %>

<p>Message is <%= @message.inspect %>.</p>
```

I expected the view to say `Message is "hello world".` since the instance variable should've been overwritten. However, it still says `Message is "type something into the form".`.

I tried 3 variants of `render` and got the same result:

- `render :index`
- `render :index, message: @message`
- `render :index, locals: {message: @message}`

I can see from the server logs that the `create` method is getting called on submit (it prints `got create request`) and it is rendering the index view (i see `index.html.erb` in the log); it's just that the instance variable isn't getting passed through.

Why isn't the instance variable passed to the view? Is something getting cached? What should I do instead?

Comment: @dbugger submitting the form calls the `create` action and renders the `index` view; `render :index` does not call the index action

Comment: It works as expected for me (Rails 7.0.4). What are the concrete actions you're doing? Can you add the whole logs to your question?

Comment: either redirect or `render :index, status: :unprocessable_entity` or you have to render *turbo_stream* response.

Comment: Can you please show your form ? What I suspect if your form is inserted into a Turbo frame and the part of the view that contains the instance variable stays untouched as only the content of the turbo frame is updated. (This is just a guess based on the code submitted)

Comment: @Alex @Maxence thanks, I didn't realize I couldn't render other stuff in the `create` action without turbo_stream. If either of you want to expand that into a few sentences I'll happily accept it as the answer. I ended up redirecting to show.

Comment: You can render a plain HTML page even with Turbo. You don't need to return turbo stream for every form submitted. But obviously there is something that is blocking the render of the full page. Your instance variable `@message` is clearly set properly in create, then should appear on page. If it happens you were using a turbo frame to encapsulate your form, then only your form would be updated, and this would explain the bahavior. That's why I wanted to see your form partial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's technically explained here:
*https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#redirecting-after-a-form-submission*

Sometimes it's hard to connect all the dots in *Turbo*.

```rb
# app/controllers/messages_controller.rb
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @message = "type something into the form"
  end

  def create
    @message = params[:form_message]
    render :index
  end
end

# app/views/messages/index.html.erb
<%= form_with url: "/messages" do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :form_message %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
<div id="message_id"><%= @message %></div>
```

If you submit this form you get this in the browser console:

```bash
turbo.es2017-esm.js:2348 Error: Form responses must redirect to another location
    at O.requestSucceededWithResponse (turbo.es2017-esm.js:780:27)
    at I.receive (turbo.es2017-esm.js:543:27)
    at I.perform (turbo.es2017-esm.js:518:31)
```

---

#### status: :unprocessable_entity

After submitting a form, you have to redirect or render an error response, default is status `422` aka `:unprocessable_entity`:

```rb
render :index, status: :unprocessable_entity
```

---

#### render turbo_stream:

Because forms are submitted as *TURBO_STREAM* format, you can render *turbo_stream* response:

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :index, status: 422 }
  format.turbo_stream do
    render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update(:message_id, params[:form_message])
  end #    ^       helper^      action^      ^id          ^content
end   # response format
```

This is probably the preferred way.

---

#### turbo_frame

Put it in a frame. Not as efficient as turbo_stream, because it renders the whole page on the server, but on the front end effect is the same, only message is updated:

```rb
<%= form_with url: "/messages", data: { turbo_frame: :message_id } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :form_message %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= turbo_frame_tag :message_id do %>
  <%= @message %>
<% end %>
```

Just `render :index` works fine.

---

#### method: :get

Send *GET* request instead:

```rb
# app/views/messages/index.html.erb
<%= form_with url: "/messages", method: :get do |f| %>
...

# app/controllers/messages_controller.rb
def index
  @message = params[:form_message] || "type something into the form"
end
```

---

#### override turbo render

Because the server is actually rendering a response and sending it back, we can override turbo rendering logic and just render the response instead of complaining:

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

document.addEventListener("turbo:before-fetch-response", async (event) => {
  if (event.target.hasAttribute("data-render-post")) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const response = new DOMParser().parseFromString(await event.detail.fetchResponse.responseHTML, "text/html")
    // you're free, do what you like here
    document.body.replaceWith(response.body)
  }
})
```

```rb
# app/views/messages/index.html.erb

# i imagine you don't want to do that for every form
#                                       vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
<%= form_with url: "/messages", data: { render_post: true } do |f| %>
...
```

---

#### redirect_to

The usual redirect then render will work. You can also have *turbo_stream* response in redirected action. Or *turbo_frame_tag* in the template if form is targeting a turbo_frame:

```rb
def create
  redirect_to message_path(1, form_message: params[:form_message])
end

def show
  @message = params[:form_message]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.turbo_stream { render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update(:message_id, @message) }
  end
end
```

And it behaves the same as described above, there is just an extra redirect in between.